# .NET MVC controller void action returns empty file in Chrome, not in Firefox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, action, identityserver3

```
public void SignoutCleanup(string sid)
{
    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut("Cookies");
}
```

I use this code from https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/signout-http.html

Firefox returns a white screen when going to this action. (Right way)

Chrome will download an empty file when going to this action. (Wrong way)

I guess this is an IIS setting? I don't have this problem on our test server.

Comment: If you capture the HTTP traffic through fiddler - is there any difference in the requests ?

Comment: Maybe it better to return Ok(); Then you have explicitly set the result.

Comment: @ManojChoudhari Done, difference is **X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff** Will check if that is the problem.

Comment: The header is the problem here: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff